# how to list all features installed in a sql server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation, logs, automation

There are other Installation related questions with similar details [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/190090/22336) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/255606/22336).

I could not find anything related to `listing the installed features in sql server 2016` though.

I can do it manually looking at the logs - as per the info below, but I would like to automate it.

After installing SQL Server 2016 I get a log file - located somewhere in these folders:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200109_205540`

[image]

A file which the name starts with `Summary_` +`my_server_name`

in that file, amongst other things I can find a list of the Sql Server Features installed:
[image]

After installation, later on when the systems are already in use, logins and permissions applied, firewall fixed, etc.

Is there a simple way to get hold of the list of features installed on a sql server instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run "Installed SQL Server features discovery report"

It is documented there: [Validate a SQL Server Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/validate-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver15)

Some examples: [how-to-find-out-what-sql-features-are-installed](https://www.azurecurve.co.uk/2017/03/how-to-find-out-what-sql-features-are-installed/)

Comment: I doubt if this report give the level of details @Marcello is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Query written by Pawan:

http://pawansingh1431.blogspot.com/2011/02/check-what-are-sql-components-installed.html

Comment: The TSQL query in the link doesn't tell if replication is enabled or not.

Comment: Link-only answers tend to be downvoted because the content *will* eventually go away.  It is far better to capture the salient details and post them here, with a link back to the original article.